# Which is more efficient - Multiple rows or multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4

**Each user will use this data at least 15 times when they are logged in. So READ is more important.**

So i have two approaches, i know this is a rookie question but I am just confused between the options:

**Approach 1**
Have multiple rows with less columns,

```
id                      data              user
1                       task1              1 
2                       task2              1 
3                       task3              1
4                       task1              7
```

And **Approach 2**
Have multiple columns with single row

```
id   task1       task2         task3        user
1    True        True          True           1
2    True        False         False          7
```

Please suggest which is a best approach, everything is heavily based on READ only. So i will literally fetching all this to calculate some permission and action. So these will be used on some major routes which users often visit.

Comment: Approach 2 is one of the worst options possible, it doesn't scale: You have to change the database and your application just because you need a fourth task... And next month that same problem, when task number 5 comes in.

Comment: Agreed but efficient wise its good right ? What if we have 1 million users atleast, there would be 3 million rows easily if its first approach @FrankHeikens

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4  is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I agree with Frank - go for the properly normalized model. The final decision depends also a lot on how exactly you are querying the data.

Comment: 3 millions rows is almost nothing for a database, don't worry

Comment: Ya may be if it grows to 30 million means and if postgress need to just search 3 records a user wont be slow ? When this approach would create a problem ?

Comment: Just gonna query data based on userid thats it @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Finding 3 rows in 30 million rows should be in the range of milliseconds (obviously depends on your hardware). The usual approach is: start with a properly normalized model first. Only de-normalize if you run into problems.

Comment: Just checked one monthly partition in one of my databases: 733 million records. And that's just one partition of one table. 30 million records is still nothing to worry about, the number doesn't count at all. It's about how you use the data.

Comment: oh that's interesting, am not aware about partition lol ! @FrankHeikens ! Apart from scaling is Approach 1 has any problem ?

Comment: No, option 1 is what you see in almost any relational database. It's fast and flexible

Comment: okay, other than scaling is there any other prob is Approach 2 ? @FrankHeikens

Comment: Yes, option 2 is good for the future, to learn from your mistakes... But before that, it will cause a headache

Comment: Please describe the operations that you are going to perform on the data exactly. That is what will determine which data model is better.

Comment: The operation is simple - it will be used to check users permission ( for example - if user has finished all 3 task they will be allowed to view a certain page ) ! So when even the user goes to certain pages i need to check if the user has finished the task and do the needful @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: So your saying Approach 2 will cause headache right ? But in terms of performance it will beat approach 1 right ? ( just wanted to know thats it ) @FrankHeikens

Comment: Option 2 is something you really don't want. Many people before you made that mistake, had their own headache and then implemented option 1. Do you want a headache or not? PostgreSQL is a relational database, take the relational approach to get it working. If you don't, prepare for a headache. Option 2 is just no option.

Comment: How many records would create a delay ? I saw you saying 700 million records just fetched in mis ! So whats the record number which can make a real delay ? @FrankHeikens

Comment: I don't now, we never need 700 million records, just a few out of this table. It all depends on what you need.

Comment: In *spreadsheets*, rows and columns are interchangeable. In *relational databases*, they're completely different things. As soon as you want to work with more than a single type of data, you'll find it hugely painful to store those values in a single column (often ending up with "stringly-typed" data), whereas the type system is designed for a row consisting of column data of different types.

Comment: I dont have any types, its simply varchar or may it can be boolean ! I belive it doesnt relate to my need @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Please be more specific. Write the queries you will want to run against these data models and add them to the question. Then we can have an answer rather than an open-ended discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing some premature optimization here.

It's very rare that a database slows down because of small quick queries like this. What gets you is usually the big search query when it misbehaves or if the indices aren't optimal for the job.

As everyone said, approach 2 is terrible because you need to add columns every time you want to add a new task. That's a typical red flag for a bad design. In addition, if you want to search these columns, you'll also need to add indices on them.

Approach 1 is the usual way, and it works well. The typical problem with this one is when you want to search based on attributes, because you have to join once per attribute, which doesn't optimize well.

In this case however, since you say this will be read at login, I guess this is about storing user rights or tasks associated with users. Perhaps you will select this data and cache it in the session so it only needs to be fetched once at login. So in this case, you should worry more about the queries that occur on every page, rather than the query that only occurs at login.

Anyway. Approach 1 has one gotcha: if the data isn't clustered, and the lines for one user sit in different pages in the table file on your disk, then it will need one IO per line. That's not really a problem with SSDs, but well.

Fortunately, postgres supports two ways of avoiding that: cluster, and index-only scans.

CLUSTER just orders the table on disk in the order of the index you specify. Since you need an index on (user,task) anyway to quickly find if a user has a task, you can cluster on that index, and all the lines for a user will be in the same place on disk, so only one IO will be needed to fetch them. However CLUSTER locks the table, so it's best to use it during scheduled maintenance. If you table has only a few million rows, and if you set maintenance_work_mem high enough, it will only take a couple seconds.

The other way is index-only scans. If you have an index on (user,task) and you run SELECT user,task WHERE user=... then postgres will use an index-only scan, and in the index data is ordered by (user,task) which means it will do one IO to get the page with the first row, and then the next rows for that user will be stored just afterward in index order, on the same page, so they're already loaded and very fast to access.

Notes:

Since you have no other columns, I'll assume (user,task) is unique, because it makes no sense to have duplicates in this case. So that can be your primary key, and you can drop the id and associated index. You don't have to use a sequence on every table if the data gives you a nice natural primary key.

"task" would usually be a foreign key to another table.